# countDownTimer isn't working, why?

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I have a service B that sends a specific number of messages in a fixed interval.
this service is called from another service A.
the code used in service A is

```
@Override
public void onStart (Intent intent,int startid)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service A Running onStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Thread MessagesThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            ApplicationPreferences AppPrefs = new ApplicationPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            int NumberOfMessagesToSend = Integer.parseInt(AppPrefs.getNumberOfMessagesToSend());
            int NumberOfSentMessages;

            for (NumberOfSentMessages = 0 ; NumberOfSentMessages < NumberOfMessagesToSend; NumberOfSentMessages++ )
            {startServiceB();
             }
        }
    });
    MessagesThread.start();
}

public void startServiceB()
{
    final Intent sendingMessages = new Intent(this, ServiceB.class);
    startService(sendingMessages);
}
```

the toasts are to keep track of what is happening
The code in service B is as follow

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service B at start ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new CountDownTimer(30000,1000)
    {
        public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {}

        public void onFinish()
        {
            showToast();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

the showToast() function is as follow

```
public void showToast()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service B in timer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

As I said I am using the toasts to keep track of what's happening. the problem is when running it, i am getting the first toast (service B at start) 10 times consequently then the second one (service B in timer) 10 times consequently with no time between them.

how do i make each of this toasts appear once every 30 seconds?

Comment: So do you want to show a toast every 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the final answer could be something like this: 
Call only once the B service and in it we will have the handler that will loop at an interval of 30 seconds..

Service B code:

```
 int loop = 5;
    int counter = 0;
Handler myHandler;
Runnable run;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service B at start ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        myHandler = new Handler();
        run = new Runnable()
        {
         public void run() 
         {
          if (counter<loop){
           showToast(); 
           counter++;   
          } else {
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(run);
          }
         }
       };
       myHandler.postDelayed(run, 30000);

    }
```

I hope this helps someone else too!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a toast every 30 seconds than you can do it by using a handler:

```
 Handler myHandler = new Handler();
Runnable run = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        showToast();                 
    }
};
myHandler.postDelayed(run, 30000);
```

If you have problem with this just post here and I will try to help you..

Comment: Still getting the same problem. maybe the problem is from service A. The toast as i said is just to test if the timer is working.

Comment: As I can see in your example above, you create a new instance of ServiceB in that for statement?

Comment: yes but i guess it is created more than once. maybe that's the problem. it tried the following code in service
 while (NumberOfSentMessages != NumberOfMessagesToSend)
   {Handler myHandler = new Handler();
   Runnable run = new Runnable()
   {
    public void run()
    {
     
     startServiceB();
      
    }
   };
   myHandler.postDelayed(run, 30000);
   NumberOfSentMessages++;
   }
it gave the force close error. What I really need is to run an instance of service B every 30 seconds

Comment: then you have to call startService() method only once, not in a for statement, and please give us a log with the force close error, thx!

Comment: the error was "can't create a handler inside a thread". i removed the thread but i still can't figure how to call an instance of serviceB every 30 seconds. let me put it this way: i have a serviceA that calls an new instance of ServiceB every 30 seconds and then close it 5 times. how can I do it.
And btw thx a lot for helping :D

Comment: With pleasure, :P are you sure you want to call the service 5 times? It's not better to call it once and inside it you can put the handler and run it only for 5 times on that interval?

Comment: well i guess it would be a better solution. but i just tried it and there's no 30 seconds delay between the toasts. i used the handler in a while statement since the number of times can be different than 5

Comment: here's the code in serviceB
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
  Runnable run = new Runnable()
  {
   public void run()
   {
    
    showToast();
     
   }
  };
  
  while (NumberOfSentMessages!=NumberOfMessagesToSend)
  
  {
  myHandler.postDelayed(run, 30000);
  NumberOfSentMessages++;
  }

Comment: you need to get rid of that for, you need two global variables in service b one will have the number of times you need the loop and the other a counter, in the runnable just make an if in which you check if the counter is equal with the number of times you need to loop and when you pass by that value you can do this myHandler.removeCallbacks(run);

Comment: Hey Thx a lot :D it's working now :D i really needed that :D it's for my final year project and i still have a lot to do :S